# how to fetch data automatically from database for drag and drop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want a drag and drop question and its options in to be fetched from a MySQL table and make all options in a correct sequence.

---

I got this working. but how to apply this for multiple questions fetching automatically from the database.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( "#savebutton" ).click(function() { LISTOBJ.saveList(); });
    });
    
    var LISTOBJ = {
        saveList: function() {
            var listCSV = "";
            $( "#sortable li" ).each(function() {
                if (listCSV === "") {
                    listCSV = $(this).val();
                } else {
                    listCSV += "," + $(this).val();
                }
                $("#output").text(listCSV);
                $("#hiddenListInput").val(listCSV);
                //$("#listsaveform").submit();
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
        <ul id="sortable">
      <li value="1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
      <li value="2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
      <li value="3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    
    </ul>
    <input type="button" id="savebutton" value="save"/>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <form id="listsaveform" method="POST" action="script.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="list" id="hiddenListInput" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the options, I suggest that you use `<input>` 
tags for the options and save the same in PHP rather than jQuery. use `<input name="options[q1]" />`  and you can post all the answers related to the questions. The sortorder of the options / questions will also be the same as the order in the form.

If you use jQuery, you can always serialize the data and then pass the same to PHP.